# Mathematical optimization to find parameters C++

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization

I have the following equation:

```
BW = Aw/ew + b0*R(1-X)/Wm + m0*N *nu_x
```

Usually, `Aw`, `R`, `N`, and `X` are inputs received from other functions of the general model; `ew`, `m0` are constants; and finally `b0`, `Wm`, and `nu_x` are parameters of the equation.

What I have been trying to do is to find the optimal set of (`b0`, `Wm`, `nu_x`) so that the model best fit observed data of `BW`.

Please would you advise any package/library/way in C++ that can take observed values as input then do optimisation process and finally produce the best set (`b0`, `Wm`, `nu_x`).

Comment: Why C++? Is this for a class or something?

Comment: My whole model is written by a former PhD student in C++. Normally, we input b0, Wm, and nu_X, and run the model, then compare simulated with observed values of BW. Now I want to do inversely to find b0, Wm and nu_x

Comment: Keep in mind that you're dealing with raw data, so you can use any language you want to process it.  Scipy, an extensive math library for python, has some nice api's for curve fitting.

Comment: I think the key point is that what you're looking for is called curve fitting, which allows you to do further research. However, your question is still considered off-topic as per site rules.

Comment: Since b0 and Wm occur only in the combination b0/Wm, the best you can do is find values of b0/Wm and nu_x that best fit the data. That said, your problem is then a linear one, and you should look up 'linear least squares' or 'linear regression'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GNU Scientific Library (GSL)](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiAhYOcnf7KAhVI6xQKHeh-BskQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gnu.org%2Fsoftware%2Fgsl%2F&usg=AFQjCNGBkiYu2G0_mt_P4XQoWhYdcZ5ERA&sig2=-zyM9cv4hU6PZNXg37zlDA&bvm=bv.114195076,d.bGQ). It is a numerical C library you can also use in your C++ programs. It has several different optimization algorithms as well as linear algebra functionality. It is well documented with enough examples to get going.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I have just downloaded the manual of GNU library. I will try to read and see if I can use it.